# How to count all occurrences in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I need to write a prolog predicate that will count all the occurrences of a given list. The closest thing I found was a predicate that counts only the first occurrence.

The predicate I must write is suppose to work like this:

```
inde(1, [1,2,1,1,2,2,1],X) -> X=[1,3,4,7]
```

The program I am using works like this:

```
inde([3,2,1,1],1,X) -> X = 3
```

I will paste the code to this below

```
inde([Element|_], Element, 1). 
inde([_|Tail], Element, Ans):- inde(Tail, Element, Ans1), Ans is Ans1+1.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't you mean `inde([1, [1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1],X) -> X=[1,4,5,8]` ?

Comment: sorry I mistyped that part. 1 is the element we are looking for in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for your problem could be this:

```
inde(E,L,LO):-
    inde(E,L,[],LO,1).
inde(_,[],L,L,_).
inde(E,[E1|T],L1,LO,I):-
    E \= E1,
    I1 is I+1,
    inde(E,T,L1,LO,I1).
inde(E,[E|T],L,LO,I):-
    I1 is I+1,
    append(L,[I],L1),
    inde(E,T,L1,LO,I1).

?- inde(1,[1,2,1,1,2,2,1],L).
L = [1, 3, 4, 7]
false
```

This predicate simply checks if the element selected is the first element of the list. If so, it saves in the output list the index of the element and call again the same predicate with the rest of the list and the index incremented by one.